# How to get validity value from input manipulated by MomentDateAdapter in an Angular Material datepicker?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, momentjs

I have created a custom datepicker component using Angular Material, MomentDateAdapter and ControlValueAccessor.

The date formatting and validity is handled by MomentDateAdapter.

I need to get the validity value that is handled by the adapter.

Things I tried:

1. Getting it by accessing the input element:

```
@ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef
```

But I couldn't find anything useful there, when the date is invalid (larger than the maxDate):
[image]

The `this.input.nativeElement.validity` shows that it is valid:

[image]

2. Accessing the moment object, also valid:

[image]

Where can I find the validity value that the Adapter have access to?

date-picker.component.ts

```
import { Component, Injector, Input, OnInit, Self, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { getUTCDate } from '../../services/util.service';
import { MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { coerceBooleanProperty } from '@angular/cdk/coercion';

import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE, } from '@angular/material/core';
import _moment from 'moment'
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-duplicate-imports
import { default as _rollupMoment } from 'moment'


const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment

export const MY_FORMATS = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
        monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    },
};

@Component({
    selector: 'app-date-picker',
    templateUrl: './date-picker.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./date-picker.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
        {
            provide: DateAdapter,
            useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
            deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS],
        },
        { provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } },
        { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
    ]
})
export class DatePickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {

    constructor(
        private injector: Injector,
        @Self() private readonly ngControl: NgControl) {
        this.ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl);
        this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }

    @ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef

    isOpen = false;
    @Input() id;
    @Input() class: string;
    @Input() placeholder = 'Select Date';
    @Input('date') _date: Date;
    @Input() setMaxDate: boolean;
    @Output() blur: EventEmitter<Date> = new EventEmitter<Date>();
    onChange: any = () => {
    };
    onTouched: any = () => {
    };

    get required() {
        return this._required;
    }

    set required(req) {
        this._required = coerceBooleanProperty(req);
    }

    private _required = false;
    public valid: boolean = true;
    maxDate = getUTCDate(moment());

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (!this.setMaxDate) {
            this.maxDate = null;
        }
        this.ngControl.control.statusChanges.subscribe((status) => {
            if (this.ngControl.control.errors) {
                this.required = (this.ngControl.control.errors.required);
            } else {
                this.required = false;
            }
        });
    }

    get date() {
        return this._date;
    }

    set date(val) {
        this.valid = !!val
        this._date = val;
        this.onChange(val);
        this.onTouched();
    }

    writeValue(value): void {
        if (value) {
            this.date = value;
        }
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }

    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }

    toggle(event) {
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    }

    close() {
        this.isOpen = false;
    }

    selectDate(event: Date) {
        this.date = event;
        this.close();
    }

    onBlur(){
        this.blur.emit(this.date)
    }
}
```